# Implementing custom classes

Tags: vb.net

I've got this code and it works, though I'm confused as to how I'm supposed to implement a custom class. The operators need to be changed and I've put together everything I've learned and been helped with so far and have this as the Class. I'm trying to change the operators into a custom class, so instead of +,-,*,/, I would use something else. Basically this is the class, and below that the full code

```
Public Class MathOp
    Public Function Add(NumOne As Integer, NumTwo As Integer) As Integer
        Return NumOne + NumTwo
    End Function

    Public Function Subtract(NumOne As Integer, NumTwo As Integer) As Integer
        Return NumOne - NumTwo
    End Function

End Class


Public Class MathOp2
Inherits MathOp

Public Function Mul(value1 As Integer, value2 As Integer) As Integer
    Return value1 * value2
End Function

Public Function Div(value1 As Integer, value2 As Integer) As Integer
    Return value1 / value2
End Function

End Class
```

And I've put together this code, which works as long as the standard operators are used. I just don't know what I'm supposed to do next.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off



Public Class Form1



Private Sub ButtonAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles m3.Click
    'Adds the numbers together and the tag remembers the operator

   Private Sub ButtonAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles m3.Click
    'Adds the numbers together and the tag remembers the operator

    Dim m As New MathOp()
    Dim R As Integer = m.Add(CInt(NumOne.Text), CInt(NumTwo.Text))


    If NumOne.Text = ("") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter the first number")
        NumOne.Focus()
    ElseIf NumTwo.Text = ("") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter the second number")
        NumTwo.Focus()
    End If

    Result.Text = CStr(m.Add(CInt(NumOne.Text), CInt(NumTwo.Text)))

    ListBox1.Tag = "+"



End Sub

Private Sub ButtonSub_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSub.Click
    'Subtracts the numbers

    If NumOne.Text = ("") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter the first number")
        NumOne.Focus()
    ElseIf NumTwo.Text = ("") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter the second number")
        NumTwo.Focus()
    End If
    Result.Text = CStr(Val(NumOne.Text) - Val(NumTwo.Text))
    ListBox1.Tag = "-"
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonMul_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonMul.Click
    'Multiplies the numbers

    If NumOne.Text = ("") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter the first number")
        NumOne.Focus()
    ElseIf NumTwo.Text = ("") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter the second number")
        NumTwo.Focus()
    End If

    Result.Text = CStr(Val(NumOne.Text) * Val(NumTwo.Text))
    ListBox1.Tag = "x"
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonDiv_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonDiv.Click
    'Divides the numbers, with a divide by 0 exception

    If NumOne.Text = ("") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter the first number")
        NumOne.Focus()
    ElseIf NumTwo.Text = ("") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter the second number")
        NumTwo.Focus()
    End If




    Result.Text = CStr(Val(NumOne.Text) / Val(NumTwo.Text))
    ListBox1.Tag = "/"

    'outputs a message box telling the user to correct the division by 0, also displays a blank result box instead of NaN

    Try

        If CDbl(NumTwo.Text) = Val(0) Then
            Result.Text = ""
            MessageBox.Show("You cannot divide by 0, please input another number")
            NumTwo.Focus()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Result.Text = ""

    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub ButtonExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonExit.Click
    'Simply closes the form
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSave.Click

    If NumOne.Text = ("") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter some numbers")
        NumOne.Focus()
    ElseIf NumTwo.Text = ("") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter another number")
        NumTwo.Focus()
    End If

    Try
        If ListBox1.Items.Count < 10 Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(NumOne.Text & ListBox1.Tag.ToString() & NumTwo.Text & ("=") & Result.Text)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Result.Text = ""

    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonClear.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
End Sub


Private Sub ButtonReset_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonReset.Click
    NumOne.Text = ""
    NumTwo.Text = ""
    Result.Text = ""
End Sub



Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim toolTip1, toolTip2, toolTip3, toolTip4, toolTip5, toolTip6, toolTip7, toolTip8 As New ToolTip()

    toolTip1.SetToolTip(Me.m3, "Addition")
    toolTip2.SetToolTip(Me.ButtonSub, "Subtraction")
    toolTip3.SetToolTip(Me.ButtonMul, "Multiplication")
    toolTip4.SetToolTip(Me.ButtonDiv, "Division")
    toolTip5.SetToolTip(Me.ButtonSave, "Save operation")
    toolTip6.SetToolTip(Me.ButtonReset, "Reset operation")
    toolTip7.SetToolTip(Me.ButtonExit, "Exit application")
    toolTip8.SetToolTip(Me.ButtonClear, "Clear list")




End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DoubleClick


    'This is part of the second assignment, double click on list items and they show up in the text boxes, still working on the other part

    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        Return
    End If

    'Get the text of the selected item
    Dim selectedtext As String = ListBox1.Items(ListBox1.SelectedIndex).ToString()

    'Split the item by the operator and the = into an array of strings
    Dim parts As String() = selectedtext.Split("+"c, "-"c, "x"c, "/"c, "="c)

    If parts.Length > 2 Then
        'Define a variable for each part
        Dim part1 As String = parts(0).Trim()
        Dim part2 As String = parts(1).Trim()

        NumOne.Text = part1
        NumTwo.Text = part2

        'Make text boxes set to part1 and part2. part1 = 1, part2 = 1
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `I just don't know what I'm supposed to do next.` Nor do we!

Comment: edited for clarification...I think

Comment: I don't know what you want to do. Do you want do add a method to the class to perform something like addition or multiplication that is not an operator? Then declare the respective Sub in your class as something like `Public Shared Function Multiply(val1 as MathOp, val2 as MathOp) As MathOp`. Call it from your project as `m3 = MathOp.Multiply(m1, m2)`

Comment: Basically I need to change + to something else that does the same thing and then go back and change my code to reflect the new operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB.NET allows you to overload certain operators, but it does not allow you to create new custom operators.  For more information on operator overloading in VB.NET, and to get a list of operators which support overloading, see [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379613%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on MSDN.

It's not clear from your question what it is, exactly, that you are trying to accomplish.  It would seem, though, based on your example, that operator overloading is probably not the right solution for what you are trying to do.  I think what you probably want to do is to have multiple `MathOp` classes, one for each operator, and have them all implement the same interface which has an `Evaluate` method which performs the operation on the two operands and returns the results.  The actually operator character (e.g. "+") would just be a string property.

**Edit**

Here's an example of what I think you actually need to do:

```
Public Class MathOp
    Public Function Add(value1 As Integer, value2 As Integer) As Integer
        Return value1 + value2
    End Function

    Public Function Subtract(value1 As Integer, value2 As Integer) As Integer
        Return value1 - value2
    End Function
End Class
```

Then, to use it, you'd need to do something like this:

```
Dim m As New MathOp()
Dim result As Integer = m.Add(2, 2)  ' Returns 4
```

Comment: I'm not sure how much clearer I can be. I need to make a new class that does the same thing as the operators such as + and then implement it into the existing code I have. I'm not asking vague questions just to be vague.

Comment: Like I said, I don't think operator overloading is what you want.  I think what you really want are multiple "math operator" classes which all implement a common `IMathOp` interface.  Then, depending on which operation the user chooses from the list, you could just create an instance of the appropriate operator class and call the `Evaluate` method on that object to perform the operation.  Operator overloading is a feature which only benefits programmers, not users.  Operator overloading would only be useful for changing the way other programmers work with your classes.

Comment: This is the task -- Create a class for the math ( "+","-") operations -- name the class "MathOp",  Extend the class using inheritance to include ("*","/") name the class "MathOp2"That's it as far as guidance

Comment: Right.  In that case, it sounds like you want your `MathOp` class to have an `Add` method and a `Subtract` method.  I don't think operator overloading is the right way to do that at all.  Operator overloading is an advanced feature of the language which has very few legitimately good uses, and this is certainly not one of them.  Since this is, presumably, a school work assignment for an entry-level course, I'm quite certain that operator overloading is definitely not what they had in mind.

Comment: I changed the initial first code block, am I on the correct path with that? Or should string be double or integer

Comment: Not exactly.  Again, it's very hard to say for sure, not knowing the full context of the project, but I'd guess that what you want is just two methods, one per operator.  Each method would take the operands as parameters and would return the result of the operation.  I'll update my answer with a simple example.

Comment: I've also updated the actual working code. The application works, but I don't think it is working by using the "Add"

Comment: Correct.  The way you have the code now, it will work, but it's not actually using the `MathOp` class at all.

Comment: I've updated again to reflect the change, but I fell like it's still not using the MathOp, my implementation seems off. The code still works

Comment: I updated my answer to demonstrate how you might use the `MathOp` class.

Comment: Getting "Add is not a member of WindowsApplication4.Mathop"

Comment: Ah, but it is!  So clearly you must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: I've updated again with a suggestion from the error correction help box, my implementation is still off as I need to get a value from a 2 different text boxes and display them in a third.

Comment: I figured out the problem to the error, was a syntax error on my part. Still working on implementation and getting the numbers from the text boxes

Comment: I have updated the working code again. I believe this is actually using MathOp. It works in the application with no "+" in sight. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Yes, that's what *I* would expect, anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your following through with me on this I greatly appreciate it. I should be able to modify things and then use inheritance to make MathOp2 for * and /

Comment: I've updated, whats hopefully the final time, the original code. I've included MathOp2 with inheritance from MathOp, though I don't fully understand why since the code in MathOp2 should work without it.

Comment: This is my last update I think. I've used MathOp2 for all of the calculations since it inherits MathOp. I didn't update the original post to reflect this.